# "Unable to open registry key <name> for reading" [Windows 10 Education]

Tags: scripting, windows-10, scriptmanager

I started getting [this error](https://imgur.com/GGGrXor) a while ago at every startup. After searching on Microsoft's website, I now know what the error is, but I don't know *where* it is. Does anyone know where to find the respective source code file so I can try to correct this (or any other way to correct it, for that matter)?

Thanks!

Comment: run Processexplorer, use cross hair from its toolbar, drag&drop it on message, this highlghts the process. here you see the commandline and on properties you see the parent process that started it

Comment: Thanks, @magicandre1981, this helped!

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer so that you can accept it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't click the message away, run [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), use the cross hair from toolbar

[image: Process Explorer CrossHair]

and move it to the Error message. This will highlight the program which causes the error message. Process Explorer whill tell you the command line, so you see where the script is located and in the properties of the script process you can see the parent process which started the script.

[image]

Now uninstall the program that causes this message.

Comment: Thank you for an official answer! :)